# Dropdown list of weeks of the current year using datefns

Tags: angular, typescript, calendar

Right now, im building a planner using date fns. Since i'm new to Angular, I'm having some difficulties on how to get the dropdown list of weeks. I have tested some examples but sadly no one works. I'm using version 9 by the way.
Photo below is the idea of the project. I hope someone can help me. I thank you in advance.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fj1KH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import differenceInWeeks from 'date-fns/differenceInWeeks';

const startDate = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), 0, 1); // first day of the year
const endDate = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), 11, 31); // last day of the year

// How many full weeks are between end date & start date
const count = differenceInWeeks(endDate, startDate);
const result = Array.from({ length: count }, (_, i) => `Week ${i + 1}`);

console.log('array of weeks', result);
```

If you are using Angular Material, then just follow this guide - [Angular Material Select](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview)

Comment: Thank you so much @Roman , you just saved me. Have a nice day!